# What is the appropriate way to mock 2 classes that implement an interface with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

I have 2 classes that implement one interface.

```
public interface DataAccess { /*....*/ }
public class DataAccessCache implements DataAccess { /*...*/ }
public class DataAccessMemory implements DataAccess { /*...*/ }
```

Now I have another class called `CPU` that encapsulates `DataAccessCache` and `DataAccessMemory` (both are private instance vars) like:

```
private DataAccessCache cache;
private DataAccessMemory memory;
```

To mock these two classes, I have 2 setter methods:

```
public void setDataAccessCache( DataAccessCache cache ) {
    this.cache = cache;
}

public void setDataAccessMemory( DataAccessMemory memory ) {
    this.memory = memory;
}
```

I want to test CPU method `put(String key, String value)` that will put `key-value` pair into memory and cache. I want to make sure that cache's put method and memory's put method are called inside put method of CPU. I'm testing like so (using Mockito):

```
public void test() {
    CPU cpu = new cpu();
    DataAccessCache cache = mock( DataAccessCache.class );
    DataAccessMemory memory = mock( DataAccessMemory.class );
    when( cache.put("key", "value") ).thenReturn(true);
    when( memory.put("key", "value") ).thenReturn(true);
    cpu.setDataAccessCache( cache );
    cpu.setDataAccessMemory( memory );
    cpu.put("key", "value");
    verify( cache ).put("key", "value");
    verify( memory ).put("key", "value");
}
```

However, the test result states there is an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at CPU.put(Unknown Source)
at CPUTest.test(Unknown Source)
```

How can I make this right?

Comment: Hard to tell without the code for CPU.put()

Comment: You're right Peter. As I implement CPU.put(), it has locking system for mutual exclusions. That means, there are parts that I have to acquire() and release() lock. The problem is that I did not mock those locks and here we are, CPU.put() cannot proceed. Thanks.

Comment: No problem - glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

You should just verify your mocks at the end.

```
   public void test() {
    CPU cpu = new cpu();
    DataAccessCache cache = mock( DataAccessCache.class );
    DataAccessMemory memory = mock( DataAccessMemory.class );
    cpu.setDataAccessCache( cache );
    cpu.setDataAccessMemory( memory );
    cpu.put("key", "value");
    verify( cache ).put("key", "value");
    verify( memory ).put("key", "value");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying ShyJ. It's not the problem you specify here. Read the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
public void test() {
    CPU cpu = new cpu();
    DataAccessCache cache = spy( new DataAccessCache() );
    DataAccessMemory memory = spy( new DataAccessMemory() );
    //when( cache.put("key", "value") ).thenReturn(true);
    doReturn(true).when(cache).put(eq("key"), eq("value"));
    //when( memory.put("key", "value") ).thenReturn(true);
    doReturn(true).when(memory).put(eq("key"), eq("value"));
    cpu.setDataAccessCache( cache );        
    cpu.setDataAccessMemory( memory );
    cpu.put("key", "value");
    verify( cache ).put("key", "value");
    verify( memory ).put("key", "value");
}
```

I havent put this into IDE, just typed it from the top of my head, but I think I got it right. Try it.